# iPad preventDefault action only on first link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ipad, safari

I have a link on my page which I want to behave as follows on the iPad.

On first click only, prevent default action (i.e. should not follow the href action) and on subsequent clicks, follow/allow default action (i.e. should follow the href action).

The code I have written is:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null)
{
var clickCount = 0;

$("a").click(function(event) { 
    if (clickCount == 0)
    {
        event.preventDefault(); 
    }   
    else{
        return true;
    }
    });
    clickCount++;
}
```

Now for some reason, even on first click, it follows the link. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to move `clickCount++;` into the callback function from the `click`-event.

```
$("a").click(function(event) { 
    if (clickCount == 0){
        event.preventDefault(); 
    }   
    else{
        return true;
    }
    clickCount++;
});
```

​
Currently, `clickCount++;` is called when the document is loaded and is already set to `1` when the event gets fired for the first time.

Comment: Its the handler, not a callback